# IntelliJ - No such instance method

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ's 12 Ultimate, I'm running the following code in the Debugger:

**Java**

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue;
public class Foo { 
 ...
 public JsValue toJson() { ... }

public class FooExample {
...
  Foo foo = new Foo(); 
  System.out.println("...); //<-- breakpoint
```

At the breakpoint, I right-clicked my source code and picked "Evaluate Expression," typing in:

`foo.toJson()`.

But the following error showed up:

`No such instance method: play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.com.foo.Foo.toJson ()`

Am I doing something wrong? `Foo#toJson` calls Scala code, if that matters.

**EDIT** I actually had the breakpoint after the instantiation of `Foo.` To those who downvoted it, I deserved it.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

My answer is no longer valid after OP modified question (i.e. moved where the breakpoint actual is)..

<strike>A breakpoint is hit before the line is executed. So in this case `foo` has not yet been declared or instantiated (i.e. the `Foo` constructor has not yet been called). You'll need to put the breakpoint at the next line (or step over the current line) if you want to evaluate `foo`.</strike>

Comment: thank you, Mark. I realize your solution is correct, but I had already stepped over my instantiation of `Foo`. I  updated my question as I had stepped over the original breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exception message In IntelliJ 2017.1.3 at debugging time.

That happens to me when I tried to access an nonexistent method for the instance, not for the class.

Common example: If you forget to deploy your code to the server and your class have a new method when you are debugging you can't watch new members nor evaluate new methods.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that issue trying to call `org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable#one` in the **Evaluate expression** window during a debugging session.
IntelliJ showed the following error message

> No such instance method: 'one'

while the code was just running fine when I did not have a debugger attached.

It turned out that my **Project language level** in IntelliJ was no set properly (can be set under Project settings -> Project).

The `one` method is implemented as a [`default` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in an interface.
My `JAVA_HOME` was properly set to a JDK 12 but the Project language level was set to 6.
After adjusting the Project language level to 12 the error was gone and I could step through the method.