# Showing member function as "Not an instance method"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, lombok

I am working with Sprinboot and tried to access the getter function of the object to get the value. It is showing `function name` in suggestions

[image]

but when using it it is giving the error `Not an instance method`
[image]

Can someone suggest, what am I missing here?

Here is the Structure of the class that I am using.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class paymentDetails {
    private String paymentId;

    private Double amount;

    private String paymentType;

    private String utr;

    private OffsetDateTime paymentDate;

    private OffsetDateTime approvalDate;

}
```

**Note**: For debugging, I am using `Evaluate Expression` here in ***Intellij Idea***.

Comment: I just saw you have already used @Data ,
it will automatically include the standard setter and getter for the entity class.

Is the error happening during you edit the code?  I don't it can cause compiling issue there.

Comment: Maybe you can only evaluate the value of payments.get(0) first.
It also can show the member value of it during debugging.

Comment: Hey @SeanH, payments.get(0) is working fine. I already checked it and it is working fine. I was earlier doing it using streams and getting the same error then switched to the iterative method from where I get this issue. Can't understand why this is happening as it suggests the getter to be a member function but when running it gives such an error.

Comment: Thanks for your information.  Possibly this can be a bug of lombok plugin in ideaJ environment.  Perhaps you can try the latest version of lombok?

Comment: Okay, will see it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with intelliJ + lombok.

You can refer to the discussion here: [IntelliJ - No such instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487219/intellij-no-such-instance-method)